# Looking for visual studio code extension for i18n resource bundle editing

Tags: visual-studio-code, localization, internationalization, editor

I am looking for an resource bundle editor as extension for visual studio code.

Is there something similar to the resource bundle editor from eclipse?
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/resourcebundle-editor

I really liked that one.

My goal is to edit multiple locale files for internationalization / i18n. I want to be able to translate language keys in multiple languages in a single editor.

My language resources are saved as:
- json
- js
- ts

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of. My solution is to use a stripped Eclipse Tester Edition with all default modules uninstalled and just the Resource Bundle Editor installed. Not great, but works and is still pretty lightweight...